# error in check datagridview cell value empty or not

Tags: c#, winforms

this code is error :

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the
>   source or destination.

i have check column where is empty or not, but not work.

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
{

    //THIS A MAPPING REPLACET WITH YOUR NEED
    for (int i = 0; i <18; i++)
    {
        if (datagridaddfield.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(datagridaddfield.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), datagridaddfield.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "profile2";
            [...]
```

i want program check this line `if (datagridaddfield.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)`
but program not checking!

Comment: try this: if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datagridaddfield.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing wrong parameters to `ColumnMappings.Add` . What you are doing now is passing cell values which doesn't make sense to Column mapping. One of the overloads should be passed the columns indexes to map. You could also use column names. Check out [SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84x0sax1.aspx) .